# Many jobs hanging after creating

Tags: qiskit, ibm-q-experience, vqe

I am running a VQE calculation running from a cluster using nohup.

However, some of my jobs keep hanging with 'creating' and therefore my VQE is not converging/not working.

However, at the same time, a subset of my jobs are still running.

Please, can you help me diagnose the problem?

Here is a selection of Job IDs of the 63 (at present) hanging jobs:

```
5dc539d363f7360011c42a62

5dc51254ac8b9a0011fb486d

5dc51254ac8b9a0011fb486d

5dc51254ac8b9a0011fb486d
```

Comment: Hello, can you see these jobs in the IBM Q Experience? It might be the case that it is just taking a long time to execute as the queue is long.

Comment: I don't think this is the case. Because every time I runs a job one is ran and one stays in my pending as creating. So jobs are still running. But some also appear to be hanging. When they all should be running

Comment: Sometimes I face similar problem. For example, I sent a few jobs to one quantum processor and some of them were simply skiped and indicated as pending. Moreover, I was able to run other jobs on this quantum processor while the previous were still pending. So, it seemed like IBM Q simply does not know about these jobs. I simply cancelled hanged jobs and sent them again.